# How to Post image created on facebook feed HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

The HTML and everything is ready, only one thing I cannot fix is to share the image that users created on their facebook post. I have created the app on facebook with the app id already. But how do I set a post button for people to share their image created to their news feed and then tag us on facebook. Please help on that!

```
 <!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" lang="us">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>〈Magnetic〉中秋祝你乜乜乜</title>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

body{
    font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin: 50px;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

html {
display: table;
margin: auto;
}

body {
display: table-cell;
        padding: .8em 2em .8em 20px;

}
.demoHeaders {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
#dialog-link {
    padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
#dialog-link span.ui-icon {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: .2em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
#icons {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#icons li {
    margin: 2px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 4px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#icons span.ui-icon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4px;
}
.fakewindowcontain .ui-widget-overlay {
    position: absolute;
 }
 select {
    width: 200px;
 }

 .image { 
 position: relative; 
 width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
 }

h2 {
position: relative;
top: 80px;
left: 360px;
width: 200px;
height: 90px;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:36px;
margin: 0 auto;

}
h4 {

width: 600px;


}

img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index:-1;
}

div.relative {
position: relative;
left: 20px;
border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}

#container {
width:600px;
height:350px;

 position: relative;
}
#image {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width:100%;
height: auto;
}
#text {
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
 left: 250px;
 top: 80px;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>


<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&  appId=146818572333211";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://game.magnetic.hk/"   data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>


<!--width:100%;
height:350px;-->
<div class="container">

    <h1 class="container">〈Magnetic〉中秋祝你乜乜乜</h1>

    <div style="display: block;">
    <div id="imgDiv" class="image">

 <img src="http://game.magnetic.hk/image.php?text=中秋祝你乜乜乜
  " />
  <p id="display"></p>
  </div>
  <!--<div id="image">
  <img src=http://magnetic.hk/campaign.png

  " alt="Placeholder"><h2 id="text"><p id="display">中秋祝你乜乜乜</p></h2><img>

 </div>-->

</div>

    <p>寫上中秋的祝福字句送給你愛的人：</p>
<form action="image.php" method="post" name="myform" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13BRrb7Y-oujmAXVcDdL_pKCPpXHrtIw7NLgJEqEb2vA/formResponse">


      <textarea style="width:600px;" name="text" id="inputtext" onChange="myFunction()" placeholder="上限為16個字">中秋祝你乜乜乜</textarea></br></br>

        <!--<input style="width:600px;" name="name" id="name" placeholder="名稱 NAME"></input></form></br>

          <input style="width:600px;" name="email" id="email" placeholder="電郵 EMAIL"></input>

      </br>-->


      <h4 style="color: #AAAAAA;">

        <p>使用細則及條款</p>



        歡迎閣下參與由MARKNEXT LTD網站<a href="http://marknext.hk" target="_blank">marknext.hk</a>的《Magnetic <span class="text-center">中秋祝你乜乜乜</span>》。<br>

        本網站會不時修訂條款而毋須另行通知。修訂的服務條款將於公開張貼在magnetic facebook page 當日起即時生效，並取代舊有的條款。讀者使用本網站出品時，需要遵守本網站訂下的指引及規則。 <br>

        Magnetic 廣告之版權為magnetic 或magnetic 委任之公司所擁有，本生成器只為二次創作，並不代表原廣告及廣告原有者之任何立場。生成器守則：<br>
        <br>

        1. 請按指示輸入內容，切勿發表包含粗言穢語、淫褻不雅、誹謗、歧視、謾罵、挑釁、虛假陳述、人身攻擊、惡意中傷、具針對性，以及損害他人聲譽等成份的言論及內容。<br>

        2. 若無本網站的明確認可， 請勿以生成器製作廣告或任何具促銷性質的材料。<br>

        3. 請勿以任何方式傷害任何人／任何機構。<br>

        4. 所有生成之圖像並不代表原廣告、本網站及管理人之立場，所生成圖像只代表用戶（生成者）個人意見，本網站亦不會對其中的內容負責。<br>

        5. 本網站擁有所有由生成器產生的創作的版權，本網站歡迎轉載，但敬請表明出處。      <br><br>

        如違反上述任何條款，本網有權要求刪除相關創作。如有不當版權侵犯問題或其他問題，請盡速電郵至info@marknext.hk與我們連絡，我們將竭力改善。。亦歡迎作出合作查詢。

    </h4>

      <!--<input type="button" onClick="myFunction()" value="提交Submit">-->
 </form>



</div>


<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("inputtext").value;
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x;

 document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML='<img src=\'http://game.magnetic.hk/image.php?text='+ document.getElementById("display").innerHTML +'\'><p id="display"></p>'

$.post("image.php", {  jsvar: $("#inputtext").val()}, function(jsvar){ alert(jsvar);
 });


    document.getElementById("myform").submit();


}


</script>


<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){


(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', 'UA-67786567-1', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @pudaykiran: How is this JSF related? Because of the namespace declarations? I can put whatever I want in there, spring, gdsn, take a pick. That does not make it a jsf thing

Comment: @Kukeltje he used jsf tags in his page.

Comment: @pudaykiran: Please point them out. I fail to notice them

Comment: @Kukeltje `xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"` these are jsf tags. Ok

Comment: No, as mentioned in my previous comment, they are **namespace declarations**, You can put whatever namespace declaration you want in in a non-jsf page and it does virtually **nothing**. Examples of jsf **tags** are `<h:form>`, `<h:body>`, `<h:commandButton>` and **none** of these are used, so there is **no** relevance to JSF in this page. Therefore I removed the jsf tag.